# Do I have to copy the DLLs from the Nuget Package to the output directory everytime I use the Nuget Package in NetStandard Library Project

Tags: c#, .net

I have a NetStandard Library Project which uses a Nuget Package with the dll's in the lib\netstandard2.0 project. Now, when I build this project the dll's are not copied to the output directory resulting in

> `Could not load file or assembly 'ProjEntry, Version=1.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The
>   system cannot find the file specified.`

Whereas, when I use this Nuget Package in the Net Framework Library project on build it copies all the dll's to the output directory.

Is there any special setting I need to do the same in NetStandard Library Project.

Here is my  section

```
<!--NetStandard-->
<file src ="ProjImpl\bin\Release\netstandard2.0\ProjImpl.dll" target ="lib\netstandard2.0\ProjImpl.dll"/>
<file src="ProjImpl\bin\Release\netstandard2.0\ProjImpl.pdb" target="lib\netstandard2.0\ProjImpl.pdb" />
<file src="ProjEntry\bin\Release\netstandard2.0\ProjEntry.dll" target ="lib\netstandard2.0\ProjEntry.dll"/>
<file src="ProjEntry\bin\Release\netstandard2.0\ProjEntry.pdb" target="lib\netstandard2.0\ProjEntry.pdb" />
```

Comment: @AdamV I do not see any Property there. It is in Dependencies-> Nuget-> MyNuget.
Is there anyway to change this?
Or should go for a Target file for NetStandard which explicitly copies all the Dlls to the output directory?
Thanks in advance

Comment: @AdamV Visual Studios Professional 2017.

Comment: @AdamV I am sorry but I do not see any references in the Project. Also I have never seen references inside the NetStandard Library Project.I guess you are referring to the the NetFramework Library project.
We have references folder there. But the affected project is the NetStandard Library Project.

Comment: Can you point me to the NuGet package? It could be something [similar like this](https://github.com/RevenantX/LiteNetLib/issues/120#issuecomment-351124571).

Comment: Sorry, you're correct. "References" shows up in .NET Framework libraries, but not .NET Standard libraries, where it's "Dependencies" instead. My mistake.

Comment: @ImmoLandwerth Thanks for replying.
I have edited my question it now contains the <files> portion of my Nuget Package.

Comment: Do you have repro you could share? It's hard to diagnose without looking at the build. Alternatively, run msbuild with /bl (binary logger) and share the binary log file that we can take a look at.

Answer (score 0):

Open the references folder in the solution explorer, right click on the reference (e.g. nuget package) in question and scroll to properties. Then make sure the 'Copy Local' property of the reference to 'True'.

Comment: He said he doesn't see a References folder in his project.

Comment: @PhilNDeBlanc That's right, because it's a .NET Standard class library. Not sure what the state of this was in 2017, but as of now the project structure in Solution Explorer looks like `<Project> -> Dependencies -> NuGet`.